# Python: How to add content of file to list from position

Tags: python, json, list

I have a JSON file containing various objects each containing elements. With my python script, I only keep the objects I want, and then put the elements I want in a list. But the element has a prefix, which I'd like to suppress form the list. 
The post-script JSON looks like that:

```
{

      "ip_prefix": "184.72.128.0/17",

      "region": "us-east-1",

      "service": "EC2"
}
```

The "IP/mask" is what I'd like to keep. The List looks like that:

'"ip_prefix": **"23.20.0.0/14"**,'

So what can I do to only keep **"23.20.0.0/14"** in the list?

Here is the code:

```
json_data = open(jsonsourcefile)
data = json.load(json_data)
print (destfile)
d=[]

for objects in (data['prefixes']):
    if servicerequired in json.dumps(objects):
        #print(json.dumps(objects, sort_keys=True, indent=4))
        with open(destfile, 'a') as file:
            file.write(json.dumps(objects, sort_keys=True, indent=4 ))
with open(destfile, 'r') as reads:
    liste = list()
    for strip in reads:
        if "ip_prefix" in strip:
            strip = strip.strip()
            liste.append(strip)

    print(liste)
```

Thanks,
dersoi

Comment: Please show the code where you decode the json data, there is a propper way to do this and get the right value for the right key

Comment: @dersoi post your code to decode this json data

Comment: If data has type dict, you could try to do this: a = data['prefixes']['ip_prefix'] print a should give you this: ['184.72.128.0/17'], then you simply define a[0] for the first entry and you get: 184.72.128.0/17

ip_prefix is the key and contains the value "184.72.128.0/17"

Comment: @Rizzit <class 'dict'>

Comment: if this does not work, then please post the complete JSON code in a pastebin url so we can see if the objects are nested.

Comment: @Rizzit I do get the error "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str"  The original JSON file can be found here: https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json

Comment: Hah, thats what I thought, give me a sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i've went through your JSON object

```
import json, urllib2

url = 'https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json'
req = urllib2.Request(url)
res = urllib2.urlopen(req)
j = json.load(res)
print j['prefixes'][0]['ip_prefix']

prefixes = j['prefixes']
for i in prefixes:
    print i['ip_prefix']
```

the result:

```
>>> 
23.20.0.0/14
23.20.0.0/14
27.0.0.0/22
43.250.192.0/24
43.250.193.0/24
46.51.128.0/18
46.51.192.0/20
46.51.216.0/21
46.51.224.0/19
etc...
```

So now you want all into one txt file right?
So you do this:

```
import json, urllib2

url = 'https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json'
req = urllib2.Request(url)
res = urllib2.urlopen(req)
j = json.load(res)
#print j['prefixes'][0]['ip_prefix']

prefixes = j['prefixes']
destfile = 'destfile.txt'
with open('destfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in prefixes:
        #print i['ip_prefix']
        f.write(i['ip_prefix'])
        f.write('\n')
        f.close
```

Best regards,
Rizzit

Comment: Well, thank you very much! I've even gone further than what I wanted to do!^^ And I'm afraid I can't even buy you a coffee for that. But there is one problem: I only want the IP with the service "EC2"... So this is what I tried to do: 
for i in prefixes:
    if (j['prefixes'][i]['service']) is "EC2":
        print(i['ip_prefix'])
But I get the error TypeError: list indices must be integers, not dict... Again...

Comment: Found how to do it :) Thanks to you! Just changed the for:
for i in prefixes:
    if (i['service']) == "EC2":
        print (i['ip_prefix'])

Comment: Im glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

I've refactored your code, try this out:

```
import json 

with open('sample.json', 'r') as data:
    json_data = json.loads(data.read())
    print json_data.get('ip_prefix')

# Output: "184.72.128.0/17"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the second `open` block as:

```
with open(destfile, 'r') as reads:
    data = json.load(reads)
    liste = [i['ip_prefix'] for i in data]
```

Although, I don't think you need to write to an intermediate file anyway, you could combine both blocks.